# How to get on my web application and in one click, tickets in XML format directly from Jira

Tags: java, angular, xml, jpa, jira

To be able to retrieve, with Jira, all the tickets, for a given interval, I have to extract them manually. That is to say that I click on the button extract in XML form.

Then on my web application I retrieve this XML file and put it in the database.

However, I would like to be able to retrieve this XML format directly through my web application.
That is to say that in my application, by clicking on a button, I launch the extraction of the file on Jira and I enter it directly in the database.

I don't know if this is possible.

Using Java, jpa and Angular, I think it is possible when you press a button, to launch an action that executes a URL from Jira to retrieve the file.

Can you help me please?

Comment: The jira server most likely will not allow your frontend to talk to it due to CORS. Instead you should probably register yourself as an application, let the user authenticate with a set oauth scope, get access tokens (https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-3lo-apps/) and then directly talk to jira from your backend to retrieve whatever information you want to have (https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/)

Comment: I think you can use the JIRA Api. They provide the client as well https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JRJC/pages/27164680/Tutorial. But you need to develop a backend for communicating with JIRA and show the response at frontend.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I will try it

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Issue Navigator and run and search, then inspect the Export, XML link you'll see something like this:

https://jira.example.com/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/temp/SearchRequest.xml?jqlQuery=%28project+%3D+FOO+AND+%28assignee+is+EMPTY&tempMax=1000

Once authenticated you should be able to use that to retrieve all the issues found by the search as XML

Comment: Not via some (angular) javascript in the browser though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !